# Assigning a member variable to the result of a block of code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, constructor

I want to assign a member variable to the result of a lengthy block of code that returns a 2x2 array. This would be done in the constructor. But if in the constructor I do,

```
def initialize
@foo = ...
       ...
end
```

Then only the first line of code in that block gets assigned to @foo. If I define a method, then I get an unknown method error during compilation, which makes sense because it doesn't know which instance to call it on. I don't think I can do 'self', because it's in the constructor so there is no instance yet.

I don't want the block of code in the class definition, I would like it neatly encapsulated somewhere instead. A class method would require making other variables available to that method that should just belong to each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dpassage's solution, but I think the more common way of solving this would be to just use a helper function.

```
class Bar
  def initialize
    @foo = helper
  end

  def helper
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I tried to do. But if I compiled this code, it would say 'undefined method error'. Because what instance of Bar is it calling helper on?

Comment: It works fine for me with 1.9.3. What version are you using? Have you tried defining the helper method before the initialize method?

Comment: You're right- it does work. It turns out I was getting that method error because I defined my method as helper(), and was trying to do @foo = helper. Thank you very much for the help!

As a side note- How does it know which instance to call helper on? Aren't instance methods all called on instanceS?

Comment: The object is already created by the time your initialize method gets called. You can try doing class Test; def initialize; puts self; end; end. Also as a side note, Ruby doesn't get compiled; it's an interpreted language.

Comment: So then constructors in Java and initializers in Ruby don't actually create instances of objects, just assign 'starting values'?

And also that calling @foo = helper in the constructor, it defaults to self.helper?

Comment: Well I don't know about java, but ruby's version of the constructor is actually the "new" method. Initialize is called after the method is created with new. So at that point you're safe to use instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should be able to do it like this:

```
def initialize
  @foo = begin
    ...
  end
end
```

The value of `@foo` should be the result of the last line of code within the `begin...end` block.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like this was a simple question but I am quite new to Ruby. Is using begin, and ends, bad coding practice?

Comment: Remember to accept the answer. :) `begin...end` is usually used to catch exceptions. Using it this way isn't the norm; as you gain experience, it's possible you'll find a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to discredit your answer, I was just asking in general. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I meant the "checkbox" next to the answer. That way, everyone knows this question is answered - and you and I both get some karma points.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lengthy "preparation" code before you actually define the array, just put the array assignment after the lengthy part:

```
def initialize
    # some lengthy code
    # ...
    @foo = something_using_the_result_from_the_lengthy_code
end
```

Or if the lengthy code is inside the assignment of the array, then you should have no problem with this:

```
def initialize
  @foo = [
    # lengthy code to assign the array
  ]
end
```